# Codeigniter 4 with PHPWord loadTemplate

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4, phpword

I have a problem loading a template doc in Codeigniter using PHPWord. The code below works but the downloaded word file is empty. I think the problem is that the location of the template is incorrect. Can anyone show/teach me how should I properly locate the template file. The template file file is located in public/template/ folder.

```
$phpWord  = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();
$document = $phpWord->loadTemplate(./template/filedoc.docx);
$document->setValue('fullName',  'John Doe');
$document->setValue('date', date("F j Y"));
$xmlWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');
$xmlWriter->save("php://output");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="output.docx"');
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Expires: 0');
```

Update:
loadTemplate is now working fine no errors, the problem now is, why is it that the downloaded doc file is empty. Can anyone help?

```
$document = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor(template/filedoc.docx)
$document->setValue('fullName',  'John Doe');
$document->setValue('date', date("F j Y"));
$document->saveAs('output.docx');
```

Change the code based on the current PHPWord documentaion for template processing. The output on the  code above is still the same, empty document or rather unreadable by MSWord. Help...

Comment: Btw you can use `getcwd()` your load template will be `$phpWord->loadTemplate(getcwd()."/template/filedoc.docx");`

Answer (score 0):

[constant `APPPATH`](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/common_functions.html?highlight=apppath#APPPATH)

> The path to the `app` directory.

Instead of:

```php
// ...
$document = $phpWord->loadTemplate(./template/filedoc.docx); ❌
// ...
```

Use this:

```php
// ...
$document = $phpWord->loadTemplate(APPPATH . "public/template/filedoc.docx"); ✅
// ...
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my mistake. The template is NOT in the app folder, it's in the public folder so "./template/filedoc.docx" is correct. Because when I ran your code an error occurred that the template cannot be found.  So it seems that it was able to find template doc but the downloaded doc is empty. Ill update my question. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

works for me

```
        $phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();

        $section = $phpWord->addSection();

        $titleText = $section->addTextRun(array('alignment' => \PhpOffice\PhpWord\SimpleType\Jc::END));
   
        $titleText->addText('helooo ', array('size' => 12, 'rtl' => true));
        $section->addTextBreak(0.5);


 

        $objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');
       
        $objWriter->save("demo.docx'");
```

its create file in public folder

Comment: I was trying to do it using loadTemplate. Can you do one that works using it?